# configure pgbouncer on Windows 7 throws c processor error

Tags: pgbouncer

I am configuring pgbouncer on Windows 7. On entering ./configure command I am getting error "c processor fails sanity checks"
please see config.log file contains:
|            Syntax error

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by pgbouncer configure 1.7.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/mingw

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = lt010
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.19(0.48/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2
uname -v = 2016-07-13 17:45

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Windows/system32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/xampp/php
PATH: /c/Program Files/nodejs/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/
PATH: /c/Users/aine/AppData/Roaming/npm


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2317: checking target host type
configure:2330: result: win32
configure:2400: checking for gcc
configure:2416: found /mingw/bin/gcc
configure:2427: result: gcc
configure:2656: checking for C compiler version
configure:2665: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 5.3.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2676: $? = 0
configure:2665: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls : (reconfigured) ../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC) 
configure:2676: $? = 0
configure:2665: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2676: $? = 1
configure:2665: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2676: $? = 1
configure:2696: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2718: gcc    conftest.c  -lws2_32 >&5
configure:2722: $? = 0
configure:2770: result: yes
configure:2773: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2775: result: a.exe
configure:2781: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2788: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  -lws2_32 >&5
configure:2792: $? = 0
configure:2814: result: .exe
configure:2836: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2844: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  -lws2_32 >&5
configure:2848: $? = 0
configure:2855: ./conftest.exe
configure:2859: $? = 0
configure:2874: result: no
configure:2879: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2901: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:2905: $? = 0
configure:2926: result: o
configure:2930: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2949: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:2949: $? = 0
configure:2958: result: yes
configure:2967: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:2987: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:2987: $? = 0
configure:3028: result: yes
configure:3045: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3109: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:3109: $? = 0
configure:3122: result: none needed
configure:3186: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:3254: result: /bin/install -c
configure:3265: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:3323: result: /bin/grep
configure:3328: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3367: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3375: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99
configure:3524: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:3524: $? = 0
configure:3537: result: none needed
configure:3646: checking for gcc option to accept ISO Standard C
configure:3657: result: none needed
configure:3669: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3739: result: /c/mingw/bin/cpp
configure:3759: /c/mingw/bin/cpp  -02 conftest.c
cpp.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-02'
configure:3759: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "pgbouncer"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pgbouncer"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.7.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "pgbouncer 1.7.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
| #define WINVER 0x0600
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:3759: /c/mingw/bin/cpp  -02 conftest.c
cpp.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-02'
configure:3759: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "pgbouncer"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pgbouncer"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.7.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "pgbouncer 1.7.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
| #define WINVER 0x0600
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|            Syntax error
configure:3789: error: in `/d/pgbouncer/pgbouncer-1.7.2':
configure:3791: error: C preprocessor "/c/mingw/bin/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CARES_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CARES_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CARES_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_CARES_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=/c/mingw/bin/cpp
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_exeext=.exe
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_GREP=/bin/grep
ac_cv_path_install='/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_CPP=/c/mingw/bin/cpp
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_cc_c89=
ac_cv_prog_cc_c99=
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_stdc=

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
ARFLAGS=''
AWK=''
CARES_CFLAGS=''
CARES_LIBS=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP='/c/mingw/bin/cpp'
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLWRAP=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT='.exe'
GREP='/bin/grep'
HAVE_CC_DEPFLAG=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=' -lws2_32'
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='pgbouncer'
PACKAGE_STRING='pgbouncer 1.7.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='pgbouncer'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.7.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PORTNAME='win32'
PTHREAD_CC=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
RST2MAN=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
TLS_CPPFLAGS=''
TLS_LDFLAGS=''
TLS_LIBS=''
WFLAGS=''
WINDRES=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
acx_pthread_config=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_debug=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
have_libevent=''
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgconfigdir='${libdir}/pkgconfig'
pkgdatadir='${datarootdir}/pgbouncer'
prefix='/mingw'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
tls_support=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "pgbouncer"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pgbouncer"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.7.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "pgbouncer 1.7.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 1
#define WINVER 0x0600

configure: exit 1
```